# how to create a data frame in python with pandas? if the case is like this?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make sentiments based on the words on the data frame that I have made and I am successful, but the expected results cannot be used as data frames again. can anyone help?

I use Ubuntu Linux and use Jupyter Notebook

input :

```
df = pd.read_csv('frakuensi.csv', encoding="utf8", names=['text', 'frekuensi'], header=1)

df1 = df[df['frekuensi'] > 20]

for tweet in df1['text']:
    print(tweet)
    analysis = TextBlob(tweet)
    print(analysis.sentiment)
    if analysis.sentiment[0]>0:
        print ('Positive')
    else:
        print ('Negative')
```

Output :

```
also
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
Negative
another
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
Negative
made
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
Negative
win
Sentiment(polarity=0.8, subjectivity=0.4)
Positive
fan
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
Negative
money
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
Negative
start
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
Negative
lol
...
```

I hope to make it a data frame but I can never make it, please help me!!

Comment: why this question have negative votes?, i don't know anything about python, but i think that if the 'data frame' could be used to analyze sentiments this question would be useful.

Comment: I also just learned to use python to analyze data, that's why I'm confused about this situation, thanks for the help :)

Comment: I voted up your question ;3

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you would like to store the output as a dataframe? Or would you like to show the "Analysis"-variable as a dataframe? Your question is unclear and it's hard to evaluate what the different parts of your code contain since we can't actually see the original dataframe.

Anyway, the print function simply prints the output "to the screen" without storing it anywhere, and thus cannot be re-used. The only variable that you use for storage is "analysis" and it's constantly being overwritten.

The easiest would be to store the information you want to turn into a dataframe as a list or an array, and then making a dataframe out of that list/array. I can explain in greater detail when you've clarified the question.